# extract large number of zips

Tags: java, android, unzip

I ve a large number (says 1000) of zips of variable size (says from 4k to 400k), an entry for zip. I manage to unzip all in the classic way but the performance are not really satisfying... Do you know a different way, nio or native based that could help to improve the performance?

thanks in advance.

sorry.. I forget to post code:)

```
    zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)));
            while ((zentry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                zentryName = zentry.getName();
                File unzippedFile = new File(staging, zentryName);
                BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(unzippedFile));
                byte buffer[] = new byte[32768];
                while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, 32768)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }


                f.delete();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                zis.closeEntry();
            }


            zis.close();
```

Comment: Why is the InfoZip version of unzip on your platform not satisfactory?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen mine was only curiosity.. sometimes things can made better I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good....

Unzipping on android will be slow. It's both the relatively low CPU speed (for such kind of operations ARM is worse than x86 for sure) and the speed of SD Card interface (remember you are both reading .zip and writing unzipped data using the same relatively low speed filesystem) - the uncompressed data might be several time more than compressed data, so we are talking about quite a lot of writes there.

There are few things you can do though to workaround it:

- do stream processing if possible - in some rare cases it might prove to be faster than unzipping the whole file upfront (for example if you only want to access few files from zip)
- unzip the files on as-needed basis - lazy, in the background ... generally - you might give some visual feedbacks to the user and let her do some stuff while your zips are uncompressing in the background (remember to give low priority to the threads and possibly pause every now an then even)